# Сумма четных элементов массива через стрим

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Создал массив array . Хочу сложить только четные индексы массива ( элементы четных индексов)

int sum = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) - фильтр фильтрует только само содержание индексов, но не по самим индексам. Подскажите как сделать правильное условие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int[] array = { 5, -999, 6, -999, 7, -999, 7}; 
                
        int sum = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .filter(index -> index % 2 == 0)
                .map(index -> array[index])
                .sum();
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Console:

```
25
```

Это помогло мне решить Вашу проблему:
[Stackoverflow: Как я могу получить индекс элемента внутри потоков java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599168/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-item-inside-the-java-streams)

### range(...)

`static IntStream range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`

Returns a sequential ordered IntStream from startInclusive(inclusive) to endExclusive (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1.
API Note:
An equivalent sequence of increasing values can be producedsequentially using a for loop as follows:

```
 for (int i = startInclusive; i < endExclusive ; i++) { ... }
```

##### Parameters:

startInclusive - the (inclusive) initial valueendExclusive - the exclusive upper bound

##### Returns:

a sequential IntStream for the range of intelements